# Implementing System Prompts in Gemini Pro for Chatbot Creation

Tags: large-language-model, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-gemini

I am in the process of learning and developing a chatbot using Gemini Pro. My previous experience includes extensive use of the GPT API, where I became familiar with a concept of "system prompts". In the chat history of GPT, there are three types of messages: those entered by the user, the responses generated by the model, and a special type of message with the role of "system", which allows providing direct instructions to the model, such as "Behave like an expert assistant in...".

My question is: How can I implement a similar strategy with Gemini Pro? I have searched for relevant information online without success. Although I have noticed that some models in Vertex AI support a specific context, it seems that Gemini does not offer this functionality directly according to the official documentation https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/chat/chat-prompts#gemini-1.0-pro.

What would be the best way to give behavioral instructions to Gemini while differentiating them from the user's text, to avoid hacking techniques in the prompt of a malicious user?

Answer (score 2):

I also just started looking into Gemini with a similar background as yourself. I came up with the following:

- I prepend the system message with the string "Hi. I'll explain how you should behave:\n" and add it with role "USER".
- Then I add another message with role "MODEL" and the contents "Ok, let's start! Please continue in your native language."
- Then I insert the first actual user message.

I have quite an extensive system message, and the above trick seems to work well.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems like a good idea. I wonder if this will be susceptible to prompt hacking techniques, if the user says something like "forget all previously given instructions"

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same problem. My solution was formatting the user message as follows:

"Your general instruction: <>
Answer the user message: <>"

It works for me, but I'm not entirely comfortable with it. I'm really waiting for a final solution from Gemini.